# Can I choose another fatality to perform in fatality tutorial mode?

Tags: mortal-kombat-9, mortal-kombat-komplete-edition

I'm playing Mortal Kombat: Komplete Edition for PC.

Whenever I do the fatality the tutorial asks, I always do it right, but I can't see any specific option to change the fatality I want to perform. The game forces me to do the same fatality over and over again without opportinity to perform any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Tutorial is made to practice the fatality that it says, not any other one. If you want to do other fatalities, you have to play other mode, not the tutorial. The list of fatalities can be found in the menu (moves list) or somewhere online (there are more than enough sites with the moves for all the characters)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can look at the start menu, in the moves list. All the characters' fatalities are listed there and you can preform all of them anytime in tutorial mode.

Comment: Please specify how do you do that, the steps? Where are the options and stuff..